# encerrar Activities no Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio

O problema é num app de quiz que está pronto, tirando esse problema.

o app tem activities A(iniciar jogo), B(perguntas), C(resultado).
na A tem um botão de iniciar jogo que clicando, vai para B. Clicando na resposta em B, vai de B para C, e clicando no botão em C, volta de C para B. E fica nesse vai e vem de B para C e C para B a cada pergunta respondida, acumulando várias pilhas.

o que eu quero é que quando clicar em sair na activity A, feche o app. Mas quando clico para sair do jogo, ele volta pra o monte de pilhas de B.

eu já usei `System.exit(0)`, `finish()`...

nada funcionou.

Comment: E o que está acontecendo com esse seu código descrito? Acontece Nada? da erro?

Comment: É bom colocar mais códigos para melhor entendimento do pessoal, tá um pouco confuso a forma que você descreveu. Mas eu adicionei uma resposta para o primeiro problema que identifiquei.

Comment: O programa roda sem problemas. único erro é esse que em vez de ecerrar, volta para activity de pergunta

Comment: @macielF eu atualizei a resposta, veja se não é isso que está acontecendo. Novamente, tente postar códigos mais completos nas perguntas.

Answer (score 1):

Quando for de uma tela para outra, e não pretende permitir que o usuário retorne, use o `finish();` após o `startActivity(intent);`.

Exemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

> Dessa forma quando o usuário retornar a activity anterior já foi
>   finalizada, ele vai fechar a aplicação. Se não for finalizada a
>   activity permanece na pilha.

**Observei o seguinte:**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PerguntasActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Se esse é o código da tela Principal, o `onBackPressed()` está sobrescrevendo o método padrão do botão voltar que é de finalizar, e está enviando para PerguntasActivity.class

O segundo trecho `onResume()` é chamado quando a activity é aberta novamente, se você está chamando ela no PerguntasActivity ele vai finalizar o PerguntasActivity e voltar para o Main que continua na pilha. Eu acho que não é um erro e sim um problema de lógica, mas sem o restante da estrutura do seu código é um pouco difícil te dar uma resposta certa.

**Tenta assim:**

```
private void ChecarExit(){
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("CUIDADO!");
        dialog.setMessage("Deseja realmente sair do app?");
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Requisição cancelada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PerguntasActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        dialog.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Ou você pode declarar um boolean e manipular o valor do mesmo durante essa transição de páginas, depois realizar uma verificação, mais ou menos assim:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
     if (isTrue()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PerguntasActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        startActivity(intent);
     } else {
        finish();
     }
}
```

(Na minha opinião pessoal isso seria uma gambiarra desnecessária, o melhor seria seguir como mostrei no código anterior)

Comment: vou tentar. mas acho que vai permanecer na activity de perguntas(PerguntasActivity.class). pq a intent ta chamando.

Comment: @macielF Sim, eu percebi agora, você quer finalizar já na activity principal e não quando ele retorna de PerguntasActivity. Por que você está chamando o intent no `onBackPressed()`? Coloca o código completo

Comment: esse onBackPressed() foi que vi na net. no caso de percorrer entre activities A, B, C e D, colocaram onBackPressed() na D e chamando a A. aí funcionou no caso do cara.

Comment: é um app pra um amigo. o app ta pronto, muito extenso.

Comment: @macielF atualizei a resposta. A última alternativa, que seria a verificação, eu não tenho como agora, mas poderia postar mais detalhes depois se você não souber como fazer.